# Make subsection text appear left aligned within the defined left margin?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

How can I make subsection text appear left aligned within the defined left margin, with its "own" margin of 0.75in (instead of 3.0in)? I believe the package for the task is `titlesec` but I'm open to other possibilities. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % no indents

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1.0in, left=3.0in, right=.75in, bottom=1in}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% subsection format setup
% \titleformat{\subsection}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\lipsum[1-10]

\subsection{First Subsection}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

This is the desired output:
[image: desired]

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Is it only the subsection margin that will have a margin of 0.75in? I mean, the subsection body will have a margin of 3in?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with `titlesec`. The idea is to put the subsection label and title in the margin with the `llap`command, and `smashing` it, so as the lines in the body remain at the same level on the page. Section title hanging w.r.t. the label is obtained  with a `tabularx` environment, of prescribed width `3in - 0.75 in`. Finally I had to compensate the interword  space inserted by LaTeX between the `tabularx` environment and the first word in the body.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % no indents
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1.0in, left=3.0in, right=.75in, bottom=1in}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

 \titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\bfseries\large\color{Tomato4! 80! }}{}{0em}{\llap{\smash{\begin{tabularx}{2.25in}[t]{@{}l@{\hskip0.4em}>{\raggedright}X@{\hskip\marginparsep}}\thesubsection & #1\end{tabularx}}}}[\leavevmode\hspace*{\dimexpr-\fontdimen2\font-\fontdimen3\font}]


\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{First Subsection with a long title}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]