# How to achieve this formatting LaTeX?

Tags: formatting

I would like to create a document that looks like this (without the colors) :
[image: Ideal formatting]

How can I achieve this formatting ?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to tex.SE... Sorry to say that, this is not the `do it for me forum`, please post what you tried as `MWE`....

Comment: Also: should the entire document look like this, or just a short portion. Are the terms to the left headings, or just some terms which are to be described. Should they be in the margin, or should they be inside the text area. Could you please narrow down the scope of this and explain what this should be?

Comment: I tried to do it with tabular but I couldn't manage to remove the border only on the left side. The @AboAmmar solution replies to it with linewidth and cmidrule that I didn't knew about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of many possibilities, as you didn't provide enough details:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX@{}}
\cmidrule(l){2-2}
Introduction & Les deux solutions principals sent:
\\ \cmidrule(l){2-2}
Terminal Server & TSE, Terminal Server Edition est une technologie de Microscft permettant de publier des applications Windows aux utilisateurs de I'entreprise. Les applications tournent uniquement sur le serveur: celui-ci envoie une image de l'application aux postes clients mais tous les traitements sont effectubs sur le serveur.

Le deport d'attichage est effectue grace au protocole de presentation RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol). Le serveur repoit et traite des clics de souris ainsi que des trappes sur le clavier transmises par le client distant. Terminal Serveur tournit aux clients Windows un acces aux applications Windows 16 et 32 bits instaliees sur le serveur de I'entreprise.
\\ \cmidrule(l){2-2}
Cltrlx & L'intrastructure CITRIX permet d'accbder via le web a toutes les applications Windows et UNIX existantes. 100\% des applications et des donnees resident et s'exbcutent sur les serveurs. Elies sont publiees en utilisant le deport de I'affichage sur les postes distants.

Grace au protocole de presentation ICA (Independent Computing Architecture), seules les informations concernant les mises a jour d'ecran, les frappes claviers et les clics souris sont transmises au poste client. Par cons\'equent les applications tournent a pleine Vitesse avec des connexions a trbs faible debit.\\ \cmidrule(l){2-2}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you very much that's perfect !

Answer (score 1):

I've used something like this in several documents. It's close to what you want, except for the horizontal rules. This should be easy to add. See the documentation for the titlesec package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% user overridable
\def\myCOLOR{teal}
\def\myFAMILY{\sffamily}
\def\myFONT{\normalfont\myFAMILY\color{\myCOLOR}}

% sections in margin
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
    {\myFONT\filleft}{}{0em}{\color{\myCOLOR}\large}
\titleformat{\subsection}[leftmargin]
    {\myFONT\filleft}{}{0em}{\color{\myCOLOR}\small}
\titlespacing*{\section}
    {8em}{24pt plus .1ex minus .2ex}{2pc}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
    {8em}{12pt plus .1ex minus .2ex}{2pc}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\section{Introduction}
Les deux solutions principals sont:

\subsection{Terminal Server}
TSE, Terminal Server Edition est une technologie de Microscft permettant de publier des applications Windows aux utilisateurs de I'entreprise. Les applications tournent uniquement sur le serveur: celui-ci envoie une image de l'application aux postes clients mais tous les traitements sont effectubs sur le serveur.

Le deport d'attichage est effectue grace au protocole de presentation RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol). Le serveur repoit et traite des clics de souris ainsi que des trappes sur le clavier transmises par le client distant. Terminal Serveur tournit aux clients Windows un acces aux applications Windows 16 et 32 bits instaliees sur le serveur de I'entreprise.

\subsection{Cltrlx}
L'intrastructure CITRIX permet d'accbder via le web a toutes les applications Windows et UNIX existantes. 100\% des applications et des donnees resident et s'exbcutent sur les serveurs. Elies sont publiees en utilisant le deport de I'affichage sur les postes distants.

Grace au protocole de presentation ICA (Independent Computing Architecture), seules les informations concernant les mises a jour d'ecran, les frappes claviers et les clics souris sont transmises au poste client. Par cons\'equent les applications tournent a pleine Vitesse avec des connexions a trbs faible debit.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249780/make-subsection-text-appear-left-aligned-within-the-defined-left-margin.