# Recreating Book-Like Section Format

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I was wondering if anyone knows how I can recreate/implement this style of sectioning in my LaTeX document? What I mean is that there is a little bit of space on each page that is blank, and the only text there is the name of that section when it starts.

[image]

For example, a page from this book has **Theorem 1.8.1** in the reserved margin space to the left, and all of the text for that section starts at the same spot in the main portion of the document.

Sorry if this is a noob question/not appropriate!

Comment: Are thouse really section titles or just theorem/example... names and numbers? How about chapter and section titles how would you like to align them?

Comment: You could have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249833/220875